# By Post request received data is None. Why it's possible

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have django app in it's views.py created for accepting, and saving objects from received data into database.

```
from .models import Hook
def hooktrack(request):  
     source=requests.POST.get("source")
     b=Hook(dsourse=source).save()
```

Than I link this view to .urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    path("hooktrack/",hooktrack),
]
```

***My full url use http protockol not https***
maybe it involved in my problem

I several times tested hooktrack view and it was accept and save received data.

```
curl -d "source=google" -X POST http://example.net/hooktrack/
```

After curling sent source=value accessible to query from dB.

```
from my.models import Hook
a=Hook.objects.all()
for item in a:
      print(item.dsource) 

...google
```

Than I linked my **hooktrack view** to production for accepting hooks from our business partner. After receiving them all of them saved to database but has **None** value

**Updated**
I inspected my Nginx logs and found that POST request and it is looking isn't as json

```
[05/Oct/2020:17:46:59 +0000] "POST /calltrackinghook/?dsource=google&dmedium=cpc&dcampaign=10393090041&dterm=+%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20+%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%88_b&dcontent=gclid=CjwKCAjwiOv7BRBREiwAXHbv3O6RZTQ_CCIENfrX0FJqtKBFhPmhF6gZFjbewnG-P-UUnHQn_5n7ZhoCtmwQAvD_BwE&disposition=ANSWERED&virtual_number=8005337639&caller=9324034020&real_number=17612021180&uniqueid=1601920016.1303437&datetime=2020-10-05%2020:46:56&duration=0&recordlink=https%3A%2F%2Fcalltracking.ru%2FshareRecords%2F2020-10-05%2F1601920016.1303437.mp3&project_id=9892&source_id=&accountcode=&landing=https%3A%2F%2Fm.05.ru%2F&client_landing=&source_name=Google.Adwords&call_region=%D0%A5%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%90%D0%9E&referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&cid
```

Comment: Did you inspect `requests.POST` ?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu can I inspect it for requsts which was done in past??

Comment: @НаглыйСпамер, you can use `$sent_http_content_type` in your `log_format` statement. [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/451572/how-to-see-the-content-type-of-a-response-in-nginx-log-file/451581)

Answer (score 0):

POST parameters available  when you submit data in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format (e.g., using a HTML form). So request '**Content-Type**' must be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.

If data send as JSON, you can access your JSON data as follows:

```
import json

def hooktrack(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    # Data is now a python dict, e.g.,
```

Maybe also interesting for you, `csrf_exempt` [decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt).

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def hooktrack(request):  
     source=requests.POST.get("source")
     b=Hook(dsourse=source).save()
     ...
```

Comment: I updated my question by nginx log's record with my view received post request snd it isn't look as json

Comment: @НаглыйСпамер, Your POST request doesn't contain `source` but `dsource`.  Typo mistake?

Comment: it's mistake only because I wrote my question code examples from memory.